# Access audio device from c code

Tags: audio

Is there a way i can send PCM (.wav) data to an audio device on raspberry pi? I am looking for something like

```
FILE* file_out = fopen("/dev/snd/pcmC0D0p", "wb");
```

so i can easily open the device in binary mode (using c code), and write samples to it.

I want to take the samples from a .wav file, process them, and send them directly to the sound card for playing (without writing them in another output .wav file). Of course, i will need to create the header of the .wav, so the sound driver knows sample rate, number of channels, bits/sample...

I am trying to avoid using other libraries, but i think this is the way i'm heading now.

Comment: are you looking for C code to do it, or a commandline way to do it? Your title doesn't match the example.

Comment: The SDL library has platform-independent support for this, and for loading audio files in various formats as well.

Comment: @Frepa can you please give me a link ?

Comment: Links: [SDL library webpage](http://www.libsdl.org/), [SDL mixer](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/) is an additional library that simplifies loading audio files and then playing them, and supports loading ogg files as well. At least on raspbian, both sdl and sdl_mixer are in the repositories, `sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2-dev libsdl-mixer1.2-dev`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing ALSA sound device is always a bit tricky. I suspect there are `ioctl` calls for the pcm devices of ALSA, but it is probably best to use a library.

There is a very small library called [tinyalsa](https://github.com/tinyalsa/tinyalsa), which already comes with an example called `tinyplay`. This could be a good starting point for you, without the need to use the heavyweight ALSA library.

SDL is also a good idea, as Frepa suggested.

Comment: thank you, i used tinyalsa, exactly what i was looking for!